# Sencha Touch on Android Emulator

Tags: android, cordova, android-emulator, sencha-touch-2

I have a Sencha Touch + PhoneGap application that has 3 tabs and a Nested List. It runs as expected on a real Android device however on the Android Emulator, tapping on Nested List items doesn't seem to have any effect at all. Tapping on tab icons changes the active view as expected though.

Do you know what would be wrong with it? How can I debug this?

Answer (score 0):

There is a phonegap plugin logger which will generate the native log from the javascript console.log() function. Install that plugin and add some console output on the click event of nested list. And you can check whether it is giving any error.